# Is my Arduino UNO fried?

Tags: arduino-uno

The title sums it all up. While testing  the new proximity detector I bought off of Amazon, a spark flew from some random area and my Arduino's On LED went off while its Loop LED stayed in a dim state. I am here to ask you guys if this basically counts my Arduino as fried and that I need a new one, or if I should wait and see if it works again, being that I wrote this 5 minutes after the thing happened.

Thanks in advance,

afroraydude

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to tell without further testing. Do the following:

1. Remove the Uno from the faulty circuit, making sure you remove all the wiring from the Arduino board.
2. Plug the Uno into the USB port. Does the ON LED light up? Does the built-in LED on D13 blink three times? (this should happen if you had the optiboot bootloader)
3. Remove the USB cable and plug the Uno to a 9V source through the barrel power connector. Do the same test above.
4. Can you upload the Blink sketch? If you can, does it make D13 LED blink once a second?

Report your findings by updating your question.

Comment: I did the unplugging and stuff, the ON LED is dim now, and the LED on D13 does not blink 3 times, it just stays on but is dim. I cannot upload the Blink Sketch, the computer does not get the Arduino on the COM port.

Comment: That's really bad... I think that this is enough evidence that it's fried. Can you check with a digital multimeter what's the voltage on Vin, +5V and 3V3 pins?

Comment: The microprocessor also gets warm, forgot to mention that.

Comment: Definitely fried. Post your circuit so we can tell you what went wrong.

Comment: i cannot due to the stuff i used, external stuff, i have realized that i shorted it

Comment: Don' get all fustrated now. It might be just the chip, the arduino chip is fairly cheap, and can be removed by lightly wiggle a screwdriver below it, buy one like $5 and replace it and burn a new bootloader on it.